# animation plot in matplotlib with data from loop

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I've made an animation program from matplotlib, following its program code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

def fung(y,v,t,w,g,A):
    import numpy as np
    return -g*v - np.sin(y) + A*np.sin(w*t)

datax = []
datay = []
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0,200), ylim=(-20,20))
line, = ax.plot([], [], '-')

g = 0.2
A = 2
w = np.pi*0.1
y0 = 0.0
v0 = 0.0
dt = 0.1
t0 = 0.0
for i in range (10000):
    t = t0 +dt
    y = y0 +dt*v0
    v = v0 + dt*fung(y0,v0,t0,w,g,A)
    t0 = t
    v0 = v
    y0 = y
    datax.append(t0)
    datay.append(y0)

#def init():
 #   line.set_data([], [])
  #  return line,

def animate(i):
    line.set_ydata(datay[i])
    line.set_xdata(datax[i])
    return line,

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=50, blit=True)

plt.show()
```

after the compile, in matplotlib figure no graphs depicted.

May anyone give me some hints?

I'm very Appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the data in a single point when you say:

```
line.set_ydata(datay[i])
line.set_xdata(datax[i])
```

So this is the resulting code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

def fung(y,v,t,w,g,A):
    return -g*v - np.sin(y) + A*np.sin(w*t)

datax = []
datay = []
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0,200), ylim=(-50,50))
line, = ax.plot(datax, datay, '-')

g = 0.2
A = 2
w = np.pi*0.1
y0 = 0.0
v0 = 0.0
dt = 0.1
t0 = 0.0
for i in range (10000):
    t = t0 +dt
    y = y0 +dt*v0
    v = v0 + dt*fung(y0,v0,t0,w,g,A)
    t0 = t
    v0 = v
    y0 = y
    datax.append(t0)
    datay.append(y0)

#def init():
 #   line.set_data([], [])
  #  return line,

def animate(i):
    line.set_ydata(datay)
    line.set_xdata(datax)
    return line,

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=50, blit=True)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `ylim=(-10,40)` or `ylim=(-40,40)` or half the graph is invisible. To gradually build the graph, use in `animate(i):`

```
line.set_ydata(datay[:i])
line.set_xdata(datax[:i])
```

to display all the points up to index `i-1`.

You might want to speed this up, using `interval=10` or increasing the display by 5 points at once,

```
line.set_ydata(datay[:5*i])
line.set_xdata(datax[:5*i])
```

---

For fun and profit set `interval=5` and use

```
line.set_ydata(datay[i-10:i])
line.set_xdata(datax[i-10:i])
```